# C# SignalR client throws " 'InvokeCoreAsync' method cannot be called if the connection is not active"

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr.client

My server's `Program.cs` contains the following lines -

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
app.MapHub<NotificationUserHub>("/NotificationUserHub");
```

`NotificationUserHub` looks like this -

```
public class NotificationUserHub : Hub<INotificationClient>
{
    private readonly IUsersStateContainer _container;
    public NotificationUserHub(IUsersStateContainer container) => _container = container;

    public async Task AddConnectionToGroup(string groupName)
    {
        var ctx = Context.ConnectionId;
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
        _container.Update(ctx, groupName);
    }

    public async Task SendNotificationToUser(Notification message)
        => await Clients.Groups(message.To).ReceiveMessage(message);
    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        _container.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
```

and my connection code in a Blazor client looks like this -

```
var url = $"{WebApiOptions.Value.BaseUrl}NotificationUserHub";
Console.WriteLine($"Hub connection should be {url}");

_hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(url)
    .WithAutomaticReconnect()
    .Build();

_hubConnection.On<Notification>("ReceiveMessage", (message) =>
{
    _notificationMessage = message.Type switch
    {
        Enums.NotificationType.NewMessage => $"New message from {message.From}",
        Enums.NotificationType.ConversationClosed => $"Conversation closed by {message.From}",
        _ => string.Empty
    };

    PageInfo.SetUnreadMessageCount(message.UnreadCount);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_notificationMessage))
    {
        MessageNotification.Show();
    }
});

try
{
    await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
    await _hubConnection.InvokeAsync("AddConnectionToGroup", PageInfo.CurrentUserEmail);
    hubInitialised = true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

I get

> 'InvokeCoreAsync' method cannot be called if the connection is not active

at the `InvokeAsync` line.

The Hub method `AddConnectionToGroup` is never called, the Hub state says connected before the `InvokeAsync` and disconnected afterwards.

The obvious culprit would be the connection URL but I've checked that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Turns out there was DI issue on the Hub which was preventing it from starting.

As you were, folks.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `Start` method you can not be sure that the connection is established and connected as document says:

> Start is a promise that resolves when the connection has been
> successfully established, or rejects with an error.

So I think you need to check the connection state:

```cs
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(Navigation.ToAbsoluteUri("/chathub"))
            .Build();

        hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
        {
            var encodedMsg = $"{user}: {message}";
            messages.Add(encodedMsg);
            StateHasChanged();
        });

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }

    private async Task Send()
    {
        if (hubConnection is not null)
            {
                await hubConnection.SendAsync("SendMessage", userInput, messageInput);
            }
    }
    
    // this is the method you need to check the connection state  <-------
    public bool IsConnected =>
        hubConnection?.State == HubConnectionState.Connected;
```

I got this code from here : [SignalR with Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=webassembly#add-razor-component-code-for-chat)

Comment: I put in a statement after `await _hubConnection.StartAsync();` like this

```
while (_hubConnection.State != HubConnectionState.Connected)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Starting messaging hub...");
   await Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
}
```
which is looping forever. The hub is simply not starting.

Comment: Is it possible to put something like ``connection.Start().then()`` in blazor?

Comment: No, although one could feasibly use a Task.ContinueWith the whole point of `await` is that it does actually wait.

Comment: @RichBryant I meant you need to find a way to check if there is any messages on ``start`` method, did you check the browser devtool? any errors on console?

Comment: turns out there was a DI issue preventing the hub from starting at the server side.